# Dart, flutter - The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Color?'

Tags: flutter, class, dart, colors, containers

Im trying to assign a container color to a class property from a models file in dart. However it gave me an error that The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Color?'.

Here is my models file

```
Driver(
  name: 'Max Verstappen',
  rank: '1',
  team: 'Red Bull Racing',
  points: '182',
  color: 'Colors.blue[800]',
)
```

And here is the container widget

```
Padding(
 padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
 child: Container(
   width: 4,
   height: 50,
   color: driver.color,
 ),
),
```

Error

```
The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Color?
```

Comment: just change  `color: 'Colors.blue[800]'` to  `color: Colors.blue[800]`, in your model

Comment: it gave me this error: Undefined name 'Colors'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.

Comment: and what type of variable would this be?

Comment: see the answer, should have answered your questions

Comment: This question could use a [repro]. Check out [ask] to improve this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of a color is `Color`.

```dart
import 'dart:ui';

class Driver {
  final String name;
  final String rank;
  final String team;
  final String points;
  final Color? color;

  Driver({this.name, this.rank, this.team, this.points, this.color});
}
```

when you call it, remember to import material package on the top of your dart file to get the `Colors` class.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final driver = Driver(
  name: 'Max Verstappen',
  rank: '1',
  team: 'Red Bull Racing',
  points: '182',
  color: Colors.blue[800],
);
```